# Linux file permission "/rwx------". What does the slash mean and how can I access my files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, rsync

I have a problem with a directory. If I run a `ls -la` I get following output:

```
/rwx------    7 1000     1000          4.0k Mar  1 09:11 Folder Name
```

It is supposed to be a folder. What does the slash mean in the permissions? I expected a `d` since it is a folder.

I have this problem on my QNAP Nas. `uname -a` shows `Linux Q 3.19.8 #1 SMP Mon Feb 13 05:20:15 CST 2017 x86_64 unknown`

I cannot access the folder or set other permissions / owners.

`chown admin:administrators Folder\ Name` -> `chown: Folder Name: No such file or directory`

`chmod 777 Folder\ Name` -> `chmod: Folder Name: No such file or directory`

`cd Folder\ Name` -> `-sh: cd: Folder Name: No such file or directory`

`mv Folder\ Name other_name` -> `mv: unable to rename Folder Name: No such file or directory`

--- Background:

I copied this folder via rsync from an ubuntu to my nas using:

```
rsync -ahhve "ssh" /home/foo/bar/ admin@10.0.0.1:"/share/homes/username/Folder\ Name"
```

Thank you for reading this question and I am happy for any help.

Comment: Can you see its attributes with `stat *`?

Comment: Gordon Davisson provided the solution in an answer beneath. I got it working by a workaround: I opened the webinterface in my QNAP and used the File Station to rename the folder. After renaming, it had the `d` in the permissions list and I could access it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a guess, but... I suspect there's a carriage return at the end of the folder's name. Depending on the exact `ls` command you're using, it may be putting `/` at the end of the folder name but the carriage return makes that show up at the beginning of the line, overwriting the `d` that'd normally be there. Try listing it with `ls -l | cat -vet`, which will translate normally-invisible characters into visible ones. If I'm right, it'll show up as something like:

```
$ ls -l | cat -vet
drwx------    7 1000     1000          4.0k Mar  1 09:11 Folder Name^M$
```

(where the `^M` represents the carriage return, and the `$` is the end of line marker.)

If I'm right you can fix it by renaming and using bash's tab completion to get the name right. Type in something like `mv Folder<tab>` and it should fill in the rest of the name including nonprinting characters; then enter a new (corrected) name for it and you should be ok.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the solution. Good job!

I used <tab> for bash completion in the first place, but I had this folder already without the invisible tab and thats why I could not see it.

Comment: `ls -lb` should work as well.